# How to add value on cell during range of date

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to VBA just learned past week through youtube.
I want my userform to be able to change value of cell based on date.

Example:

```
(A2:A10): Person name
(B2:B10): Birthday
(C2:C10): Target Cell
```

If I want that person who have birthday 
`JAN, FEB, MARCH, APRIL` in target cell to be JFMA with help of userform.
How can I do this? Thank you

Comment: why do you want to do it with Vba? A simple Excel formula can do it

Answer (score 0):

Use the below formula in column C:

```
=IF((OR(TEXT(B2,"MMM")="Jan",TEXT(B2,"MMM")="Feb",TEXT(B2,"MMM")="Mar",TEXT(B2,"MMM")="Apr"))=TRUE,"JFMA",IF((OR(TEXT(B2,"MMM")="May",TEXT(B2,"MMM")="Jun",TEXT(B2,"MMM")="Jul",TEXT(B2,"MMM")="Aug"))=TRUE,"MJJA",IF((OR(TEXT(B2,"MMM")="Sep",TEXT(B2,"MMM")="Oct",TEXT(B2,"MMM")="Nov",TEXT(B2,"MMM")="Dec"))=TRUE,"SOND")))
```

Comment: @PrasetyaGiri glad to hear that i help. if you are satisfy with the answer please void it.